# How to display child window on grid click (using mvvm approach)

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, binding

I am a c# silverlight beginner and i have to use mvvm approach to achieve my task.
I have already created a GUI which look like this:

[image: http://prntscr.com/3c6ak5]

```
<UserControl x:Class="DEV_CENTER.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
              xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DEV_CENTER"
             xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:ProgramViewModel x:Key="ProgramViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <data:DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="gridPrograms" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Progr}" IsReadOnly="True"  DataContext="{StaticResource ProgramViewModel}" >
            <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="SerialNumber" Binding="{Binding Path=SerialNumber}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" Width="3*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
            </data:DataGrid.Columns>
        </data:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now i have to create a child window by clicking on "`sso`" and another child window for "`program2`" click which are just below the heading(`SerialNumber`).This child window will contain some button and text box as well.

Where should i make change to do so.I have to use Mvvm approach to do so. 
Is using "selection list" a right approach, **If i use "selection list" then how to bind it and how to link it with Model.cs and ViewModel.cs ? Could some one please help me to give  piece of codes for ViewModel.cs and Model.cs  and View.xaml?**
Would be a big help. Thanks

Comment: @Jossef Thanks for thze edit , i will put the snap shots like this in future. But do you have idea how to achieve the target which i am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

### Wrote a small demo app - [Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2s5MYtG6CQuazV0RE82N3pPa0U)

[image]

[image]

---

**First approach - Bind to `DataGrid.SelectedItem`**

Place a property in the ViewModel called `SelectedProgr`

then in the XAML bind the DataGrid's SelectedItem property to it:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Progr}" 
          ...
          ...
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedProgr, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Afterwards create a custom view that depends on the `SelectedProgr`

for example:

```
<Label Text={Binding Path=SelectedProgr}>
```

---

**Second approach - Using `RowDetailsTemplate`**

Example from [wpftutorial.net](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Progr}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="SerialNumber" Binding="{Binding Path=SerialNumber}" Width="2*"></DataGridTextColumn>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Width="2*"></DataGridTextColumn>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" Width="3*"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Put here your custom view -->
            <Image Height="100" Source="{Binding Image}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Big thanks..but how to change viewmodel.cs and model.cs if i select the first option of"selectedItem". Suppose my child window is "sample.xaml". then how to make corresponding changes in viewmodel.cs and model.cs ?

Comment: @user234839 in your 'viewmodel.cs' you will create a property named SelectedProgr. later on the XAML you will bind to this property.

need an example for the viewmodel.cs?

Comment: thanks but i have a confusion that how will complier know that it is "ss0" click or "Program2" click. because if i do this "SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedProgr, Mode=TwoWay}" then i have confusion that how will the code behind in viewmodel.cs know that which grid click it is? coukd you please give a little piece of code in viewmodel.cs ? would be a big help..Thanks

Comment: I am using c# and Silverlight-5 beginnner i dont know about the question you asked but  "i am trying to do using mvvm approach". I have mainpage.xaml(view) and viewmodel.cs and model.cs and the view is the snapshot that i shown you and i have to display a window on the grid clicks. These Windows will further contain the informations about the clicked grid.

Comment: its .net Framework i guess, but the libraries i have included are using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51178/discussion-between-user234839-and-jossef-harush)

Comment: yes it is working but , I wanted to open window on grid cell click NOT BUTTON CLICK. This code open window on Button click. What i want is : I already have a grid like "ss0" and on clicking to it should show childwindow. Could yo uplease help me in doing this ? please I am stuck here since long time.

Comment: I have a problem in the same. If you could help me on this link would be a big help..Thanks? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251123/why-tooltip-not-changing-display-on-second-grid-mouse-hover-of-same-column